# Other analogies similar to "flu and "influenza"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, analogy

Medically speaking, *flu* is a derivative of *influenza*; but in common usage *flu* includes colds and other flu-like symptoms. *Influenza* is a condition caused by specific viruses. While colds are also caused by a virus, the viruses are different and distinct and produce different though similar symptoms.

I want to find another example of words that describe specific as well as global situations/conditions that are used interchangeably by the public yet have distinct technical differences.

Comment: _Hacking_ vs. _cracking_ is probably one. You might want to browse through the [ambiguity](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ambiguity) tag page for other candidates.

Comment: *madness*: insanity; the state of being mentally ill, esp. severely. Also, any emotion of abnormal degree in general. Also, a layman's term for rabies. Also, (ah well, don't start getting mad now).

Comment: The word *flu* has no other meaning than a short-cut for *influenza*.  Figurative uses such as the *blue flu* are something else.  A cold is not the flu, and food poisoning is not the flu; neither is viral gastroenteritis or tetanus, rabies or heart disease.

Comment: Before this question was closed I was going to suggest "hard drive". Non-techies often use this term for the 'big box' part of a PC that you plug the monitor, keyboard and mouse into. Like using flu to describe a cold, it's incorrect but has become common usage. But it's not an abbreviation.

Comment: @tchrist I think the OP means that people often (incorrectly) say that they've got the flu, when they've simply got a cold.

Comment: @tinyd Non-techies also say *hard drive* when they mean filesystem or partition.  The whole *hard drive* thing marks you as a non-techie.

Comment: Frankly, there are many, many terms that have specific technical meanings and also general, everyday meanings. In some cases you could say that the non-professionals are using the term incorrectly; in other cases it would be more realistic to say that the word simply has multiple definitions. Like, to a physicist, "work" means force expressed over distance. But in everyday language, we say "I did a lot of work" when we mean we were sitting at a desk shuffling paper, and probably expended very few joules. To an IT person "memory" means something much more specific than it does in common use....

Comment: ... Likewise a "key" is something very different to an IT person than to a locksmith. "Object" means different things to an IT person than to an astronomer, and both are quite different from what the word means in everyday use. (Sorry for all the IT examples, but I'm an IT guy.) It would be silly to say that the astronomer is "wrong" because he uses the word object to mean something different than the IT person means, or vice versa. I think a lot of statements that lay people are using a word inaccurately because they use a more general definition than a technical meaning is equally silly.

Answer (score 1):

This can go in both directions, with the stricter meaning being broader, as well as it being narrower. Sometimes it can even overlap.

*Meningitis* technically means any inflammation of the meninges, but is often used to name any of the several infections that have it as a symptom.

*E-mail* and *email* can - and did - mean any of several forms of electronic delivery of messages over a network (whether actually transmitted over the network, or with the messages remaining on one computer shared by several users). Now it almost always only means the form of Internet email most commonly used.

*Atheism* technically means only a belief that there is no god, but is often taken to mean a disbelief in several other religious ideas.

*Overdose* means you have taken more than the prescribed dose, even if only trivially, but is often taken to mean a dangerous overdose.

*Abortion* in relation to a pregnancy technically means an event in which the pregnancy ended before full-term, but is often taken to mean only an induced abortion (and there's a reason why people who don't know medical terms shouldn't read their medical records - I've heard more than once of a woman being upset to read her miscarriage described by the technically correct *abortion*).

Some come from words being borrowed from other cultures. *Tantra* technically refers to a range of related styles of religious practice, but in English often refers only to a particular subset (most often those with a sexual component - sex sells).

And many trade-marked items came to refer to rival products. E.g. *Hoover* is the name of a company, and a trade-mark, but in many places *hoover* refers to a vacuum cleaner regardless of manufacture, or as a verb to using a vacuum cleaner.

Comment: These are all good and close but not exactly what I was hoping for. I know there is something out there. I can almost taste it. But I cannot quite find it. In common parlance, Flu often includes what, in reality, is simply a cold. The CDC does not use the term "flu" but rather "Ifluenza Like Illness -- ILI" Attempting to explain that and including the viruses that cause both colds and flu leaves people glazed over. I'm looking for a common situation I can use as an analogy to improve their understanding.

Comment: For example (but not quite good enough) The Heavens refers to the physical space above us including the stars. Heaven is concept that implies a non-geographic, non-specific location.

Comment: @RandyMartin so it has to be an informal abbreviation to count? Otherwise *atheist* above fits the bill - a Zen Buddhist would be an atheist (no belief in god), but their belief in reincarnation would be outside of informal use of *atheist*.